# Debugging an app launched through scheduled tasks

Tags: winforms, debugging, .net-3.5, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

How do I debug an application which is launched via scheduled tasks?

I have a simple application which works fine when double clicked to launch, but it doesn't work when launched through scheduled tasks.

I know how to debug projects on a local computer, but this application has no issues running on a local computer or on a different computer if launched manually by the user by double clicking the executable file.

I need a way to debug the application when it's being launched by scheduled tasks.  Is this possible?

Comment: winforms tag? For a scheduled task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would primarily suggest putting in some decent logging so that you can diagnose problems without resorting to the debugger. However, to launch the debugger, you can either attach it to an existing process in Visual Studio (using Debug/Attach to process... menu), or change the code to include the `Debugger.Launch()` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx) which will launch the debugger and attach it to the process. Of course all of this is dependent on your program actually being executed by the scheduler. If the scheduler doesn't execute the program, then the debugger obviously can't attach to it