# Debugging a process that has not been started yet?

Tags: windows, debugging, visual-studio-2017, scheduled-tasks, dotpeek

I am currently trying t debug a schedule task using dot peek  symbolserver and visual studio.

Problem is that the process which runs the task, is not available until I start the task, which timingwise causes someproblems with breakpoints having to catch the function being executed.

Any suggestions to how one could debug a schedule task.

More specific to the case:

I don't have access to the code, which is why i use dotpeek to see where it goes wrong. The code should work as it is. I am looking for what enviromental changes may have caused this to not function, or where exaclty in the code is it faulting and why

Comment: Set the [Image File Execution Options](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2004/04/28/image-file-execution-options/).

Comment: @IInspectable what exactly?

Comment: The *Debugger* value for your executable.

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions to how one could debug a schedule task.

You can try to include the method [Debugger.Launch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx) in your code.

> Debugger.Launch: **Launches and attaches a debugger to the process**.

Certify: [Debugging an app launched through scheduled tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20679726/debugging-an-app-launched-through-scheduled-tasks)

Comment: I don't have access to the code, which is why i use dotpeek to see where it goes wrong.  The code should work as it is.  I am looking for what enviromental changes may ave caused this to not function, or where exaclty in the code is it faulting.

Comment: @famle, If you could not access to the code, it seems we could not debug a schedule task wit Visual Studio currently, you may have to find out where exactly in the code is it faulting :(.